# Motion key for next highlighted item?

Tags: cursor-motions, highlight, spell-checking

Using the normal spell-check mechanism in vim one can jump from one misspelling to the next using `]s`. Sadly vim's spell-check is completely useless for Turkish. Using the [vimchant](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2345) plugin that hooks into the Enchant spelling system (which in turn gets its Turkish from hunspell)* it is actually possible to get Turkish spell checking enabled in a vim buffer. However the fun and games seems to end with highlighting mismatches. The words are highlighted in the buffer but there seems to be no other smarts.

I can live without automatic suggestions, replacements etc. I can spell in Turkish when I stop to think about it. But navigating through a document fixing mistakes is painful. Even using paragraph, sentence and word motion commands it is still  tedious.

Is there a way I can setup a binding to jump to the next item in the spelling mistake highlight group?

<sub>* Yes, this is turtles all the way down.</sub>

Comment: I take it that you could not generate a valid Turkish spell file for Vim (:h spell-mkspell) ?

Comment: @VanLaser No, at least not one that works worth beans. Turkish is an  agglutinated language and coming up with a comprehensive word list for it is near impossible. The spell checker needs to understand bits of the grammar to have a fighting chance of being useful in the real world.

Comment: I ask because I had problems with Romanian, and solved it. Did you try using the word list files from a recent version of hunspell or myspell? E.g. something like the `dict_aff...` from https://code.google.com/p/tr-spell/downloads/list or similar/newer/more comprehensive.

Comment: @VanLaser What is recent? It's probably been at least a year since I last tried that route.

Comment: I mean, it's not clear what the problem is (is it the number of words, or the Vim understanding of grammar)

Comment: If you run this command, with cursor over a bad-spelled word (as highlighted by your plugin), what's the result? `:echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')` There seem to be an issue getting any syntax information (at least on my machine).

Answer (score 3):

I will only give a beginning of an answer. First, because the [vimchant](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Vimchant) plugin uses [matchadd](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Vimchant/blob/master/autoload/vimchant.vim#L127) to highlight items, you *can not* (to my knowledge) search for `SpellBad` highlighted items.

**One** way would be to change that line to

```
:execute 'syntax match SpellBad "\C\V\<' . word . '\>"'
```

instead. Then, you can search for bad-spelling in your buffer with:

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")
```

and moving the cursor from a word to the next one, until the result is `'SpellBad'`. Automate that, and you have your answer.

**Another** way (better, I think), would be again to slightly modify the plugin - simply save the local variable [spelling_errors](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Vimchant/blob/master/autoload/vimchant.vim#L110) to a global one (e.g. `g:spelling_errors`) on the following line. Then, create a function (can be in your vimrc) that searches forward, from the current cursor position, for *any* of the words in that list (or, alternatively, move from word to word until it finds one that belongs to the list).

I am now on Windows, and don't have an `enchant` executable, so I can't help more.