# Is there a way to tab through fields and values in a JSON file in Vim?

Tags: filetype-javascript

Is there a way to tab through fields and values in a json file in Vim as you would form fields on a web form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not native way to do this however a few mappings should do the trick.

Add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <tab> :<c-u>call search('\v("<bar>null<bar>\d+<bar>true<bar>false<bar>\[\]<bar>\{\})\ze\n=\s*[]:,}]')<bar>execute "normal! vi". (getline('.')[col('.')-1] == '"' ? '"' : 'w')<cr>
xmap <buffer> <tab> <esc>`>l<tab>
```

The basic idea is to search for items followed by `,`, `}`, `]`.

For more information see:

```
:h :search
:h <bar>
:h /\|
:h /\ze
:h :execute
:h :normal
:h getline()
:h col()
:h c_CTRL-U
```

Comment: Nice quick fix. It might break though, if you are sitting inside a string which contains one of the matching patterns. There have been [a couple](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4348#4350) of [questions](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4050#4265) recently about looking up the syntax attached to characters. That could be used to skip unwanted matches.

Comment: It would break if the latter part of the mapping didn't use `vi"` to actually select the string. You could also do some [fancy look-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11859562/438329) to avoid sniffing syntax.

Comment: Awesome. This mapping is smarter than me.